# How to find P(Y1 < Y2 <... <Yn)

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have set of independent and identically distributed (iid) variables: Y1 , Y2 , Y3 ,…, Yn.
Find the probability that Y1 < Y2 < Y3 <…< Yn.

I am quite clueless about this question. Do I have to show it using Central limit theorem?

Since I already know that Y1 < Y2 which is less than Yn. So, I can find P(Y1 < Yn). Is it correct?

It follows continuous distribution.

Comment: Are the inequalities strict? Do we know something about $\Pr\{X_1=X_2\}$?

Comment: Yes. And this is the only information that is given. These are continuous variables though

Comment: @puffles you should put that information in the question -- it is very important!

Comment: Also, you might try solving the problem for $n=2$ for a particular distribution. The key here is symmetry.

Comment: @puffles The question is, if $Y_i$ are continuous or not. Is this information given or not?

Comment: @callculus It is not given. I am assuming here. But what would the solution be in either cases

Comment: I doubt there is a general formula for continuous and discrete variables. But it seems that you got an answer which is sufficient for you.

Comment: @callculus Just assuming it is continuous, what would be the general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any ordering of the random variables $Y_i,\ i=1\ldots n$ is equally likely, and there are $n!$ possible orderings, so the answer is
$$\frac{1}{n!}$$

Comment: How does it prove that Y1 < Y2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above (cant comment yet).
You have a total of n! possible orderings. Only **one** of those orderings will have Y1< Y2 < Y3...Yn.